# Is it safe to use 'str1 < str2' when any of the input strings possibly represent a numeric value larger than 'Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, numbers, string-comparison

I would like to use `str1 < str2 ? -1 : str1 > str2` for alphabetic ordering.

However, my input strings represent large integers (in hexadecimal format, for all it matters).

Is it safe to use the above comparison even when any of the input strings represent a numeric value larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, or will NodeJS cast those `String` objects to `Number` objects before comparing them (in which case, I'd be at risk of data-loss)?

Comment: `"10" < "2"` is `true` because `"1" < "2"`. So, no - it's not safe regardless of what numbers you have.

Comment: ***in hexadecimal format, for all it matters***. -- Yes it matters! I suggest you to convert your `Hex` numbers into `Long`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11194581/2159528 Then compare.

Comment: @VLAZ: I'm looking to make alphabetic ordering ("10" indeed comes before "2"). 
So in my perspective, it is safe if and only if the input strings are **not** converted to numbers.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette: They can be larger than `Long`.

Comment: Look here about string comparison limit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28841863/2159528

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not safe to use and it doesn't even depend on `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. The comparison will use lexicographical sorting:

```js
console.log("10" < "2"); //true
console.log(10 < 2); //false
```

Instead, you can use [`String#localeCompare` with the numeric option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Numeric_sorting). This will use numeric collation on the strings and can handle numbers correctly:

```js
console.log("10".localeCompare("2", undefined, {numeric: true})); // `1`: "10" is larger
```

```js
const tooLargeA = "9999999999999999";
const tooLargeB = "10000000000000000";

console.log(tooLargeA);         // 9999999999999999
console.log(Number(tooLargeA)); // 10000000000000000

console.log(
  `${tooLargeA}  <  ${tooLargeB}:`, 
  Number(tooLargeA) < Number(tooLargeB)
); // false
console.log(
  `${tooLargeA} === ${tooLargeB}:`,  
  Number(tooLargeA) === Number(tooLargeB)
); // true
console.log(
  `${tooLargeA}  >  ${tooLargeB}:`,
  Number(tooLargeA) > Number(tooLargeB)
); // false

console.log(
  `"${tooLargeA}".localeCompare("${tooLargeB}", undefined, {numeric: true})`,
  tooLargeA.localeCompare(tooLargeB, undefined, {numeric: true})
); // `-1`: "9999999999999999" is smaller
```

If you're just looking for lexicographical sorting, then the size and type of the characters in the string is irrelevant: `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"` can be compared to anything and it will be correct, so the *string* `"1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123"` is not in any way differentiated.

```js
const tooLargeA = "9999999999999999";
const tooLargeB = "10000000000000000";

console.log(
  `"${tooLargeA}"  <  "${tooLargeB}":`, 
  tooLargeA < tooLargeB
); // false
console.log(
  `"${tooLargeA}" === "${tooLargeB}":`,  
  tooLargeA === tooLargeB
); // false
console.log(
  `"${tooLargeA}"  >  "${tooLargeB}":`,
  tooLargeA > tooLargeB
); // true
```

Comment: I'm looking to make alphabetic ordering ("10" indeed comes before "2"). So in my perspective, it is safe if and only if the input strings are **not** converted to numbers. I do not care about the corresponding number comparison (**unless** it eventually takes place "against my will").

Comment: In that case, it doesn't matter what strings you compare. String comparison is string comparison and will just be using lexicographical sorting of characters.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to assert - that NodeJS doesn't "decide" to convert them to numbers just because it can.

Comment: @goodvibration I've added this to the answer. But no - it makes no sense to convert the string to a number before comparing. It results in very strange behaviour - what would you get when you do `"10" < "2"` - `true` (string comparison) or `false` (numeric sorting)? And what if you have `"10" < "a"` - would `"a"` be converted to `NaN` in which case the result would be `false` as would `"10" === "a"` as well as `"10" > "a"`? It makes no sense to do any conversion when you're comparing strings. Unless you opt into it with the numeric collation.

Answer (score 1):

According to [ecma-262](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-abstract-relational-comparison)

When using `'str' < 'str2'`

7.2.13 Abstract Relational Comparison

```
If Type(px) is String and Type(py) is String, then

    If IsStringPrefix(py, px) is true, return false.
    If IsStringPrefix(px, py) is true, return true.
    Let k be the smallest nonnegative integer such that the code unit at index k within px is different from the code unit at index k within py. (There must be such a k, for neither String is a prefix of the other.)
    Let m be the integer that is the numeric value of the code unit at index k within px.
    Let n be the integer that is the numeric value of the code unit at index k within py.
    If m < n, return true. Otherwise, return false.
```

At no moment occurs an integer conversion (at least not in the way you mean)

Algorithm would be something like

```
if (str1.startsWith(str2)) return false
if (str2.startsWith(str1)) return true

for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; ++i) {
  if (str1[i] !== str2[i]) {
    k = i;
    break;
  }
}
return str1.codePointAt(k) < str2.codePointAt(k)
```

So you can use operator < with string on both side (whether they hold an "int" or not).

Now does it makes sense to get '10' < '100', likely not but depends on your usecase.