# Max length for a function parameter

Tags: javascript, function-parameter

Is there any max length for a JavaScript function() parameter?

I created a function which had a long parameter, but it didn't work. When I shortened the parameter of the same function, it worked. Does that mean that there is a maximum length for a function argument? If so, please recommend alternatives to my current method.

**JavaScript**

```
function example(idnum) {
   alert(idnum);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div onclick='example(*php variable,no special character included*)'></div>
```

When the PHP variable is long, such as "17b6f557969619544eb1e6cd58c3f341", it does not work. But if I change the variable to something like "203", the function works successfully.

Comment: Let's see the code you were using.

Comment: What exactly does "it didn't work" mean? Did you get an error?

Comment: Maybe you have unsupported characters in your function argument? Please read variables restrictions at mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals

Comment: actually the parameter is a php variable. I have done similar php variable insertions in function parameter but, they were short, so i guess worked. But the same method doesn't work with lengthy php variables.

Comment: We need some code and examples.

Comment: Can you share the output of `<pre><?= $your_var ?></pre>` (from page source) so that we know what's happening there?

Comment: There is no limitation. but it depends on implementation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum length of variable name in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809153/maximum-length-of-variable-name-in-javascript)

Comment: Did you define the variable `17b6f557969619544eb1e6cd58c3f341` anywhere, or did you output a string literal or something?

Answer (score -1):

> "Douglas Crockford"  wrote in message
>   news:9a027$3fa7c56d$44a4aebc$9152@msgid.meganewsse rvers.com...
>   [color=blue]
>
> > ... . The maximum length with will be implementation-specific. ...[/color]
>
> In microsoft.public.scripting.jscript, Michael Harris
>   (Microsoft.MVP.Scripting), who might be expected to know, quoted:-
>
> In JScript,
>   variant string variables have the same limit as in VBScript, up to
>   2^31 characters.
>
> String *literals* (as in "this is a literal") have (IIRC) a limit
>   ~2^10 (1024) characters.
>
> - for the JScript implementation.
>
> > Blockquote

Comment: Where did you copy that quote (including the bb markup) from, or is it just a formatting mistake and "Douglas Crockford wrote…" is not supposed to be part of the quote?

Comment: Seems to be from http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/92088-max-allowed-length-javascript-string#post308604

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you actually want to pass the PHP variable's value literally to the function, not as a variable name.

```
example(17b6f557969619544eb1e6cd58c3f341)
```

tries to call the function with that variable (likely causing an exception, or even being a syntax error), while

```
example(203)
```

calls the function with the number literal for the integer `203`. If you want to pass the value as a string, use `json_encode`!

Also notice that you will need to escape everything for use in a HTML attribute (i.e. escape quotes, < and >), as you have

```
<div onclick=" [some code here] ">
```